# jQuery: how to add height of childrens divs with class to parents divs with class

Tags: jquery

I have some divs with `class="parent"`, where part of them contain div or divs with `class="image"`. I would like to add to these parent divs, which contain image divs a height of the first image div.  Image divs in each div parent have different heights.

The code below gets the height of the first image div, and adds it to all parent divs.  While I want to add to each parent div the height of it really child image div.

```
var p = $('.image')
var maxheight = p.height()

$('.parent').filter(function() {
    return $(this).has('.image');
}).height(maxheight);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps posting some HTML would help. I'm not sure I can understand your question as is.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Could you please reword the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over your image divs:

```
var p = $('.image');
p.each(function(index, item) {

});
```

Now, assuming that your "parent" div is actually the parent container of your image, then you can do this:

```
var p = $('.image');
p.each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).parent().height($(item).height());
});
```